# Let $p_1,...,p_s$ be a maximal system of irreducible divisors, pairwise non-associated, of $ab$ in a euclidean domain.

Tags: ring-theory, prime-factorization, euclidean-domain, least-common-multiple

**Problem**:

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero elements of euclidean domain $A$ and let $p_1,...,p_s$ be a maximal system of irreducible divisors, pairwise non-associated, of $ab$.

Writing 
$a=up_1^{e^1}...p_{_s}^{e^s}$ and $b=v_{p_1}^{f^1}...p_{_s}^{f^s}$ for $u,v \in A^x$

I wish to show that the $lcm(a,b)$ ~ $p_{_1}^{h^1}...p_{_s}^{h^s}$ (they are associates) where $h_i=max(e_i,f_i)$ for $1\leq i \leq s$.

My working definition of the $lcm$  say $m$ of {$a_1,...,a_s$} in a euclidean domain is:

$i)$ $m$ is nonzero and  {$a_1,...,a_s$}  each divide $m$

$ii)$  if a nonzero element $c \in A$ is divisible by {$a_1,...,a_s$} then $m|c$.

**Thoughts**:

I am having difficulty using the defintion to show that $p_{_1}^{h^1}...p_{_s}^{h^s}$|$m$. Any hints appreciated.